# Find the name(s) of students who have secured maximum marks in each subject

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group

Write a query to display subject names and student name who have secured maximum marks in each subject ordered by subject_name in ascending order. The solution has to be implemented in subquery.

I have used below query :

```
 select subject_name, student_name
 from subject s
 inner join mark m
 on s.subject_id=m.subject_id
 inner join student s1
  on m.student_id=s1.student_id
  where student_id in  (select student_id
                          from mark
                         having max(value)
                          group by s.subject_id)
  order by s.subject_name;
```

But this code gives an error at the 10th line of invalid relational operator

PLEASE HELP!!

Comment: `GROUP BY` has to come before `HAVING` -- `... group by s.subject_id having max(value) ...`. But just `max(value)` is no Boolean expression. You're missing something there.

Comment: Looks like homework or an assignment to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
SELECT
    SB.SUBJECT_NAME,
    S.STUDENT_NAME
FROM
    STUDENT S,
    SUBJECT SB,
    (
        SELECT
            STUDENT_ID,
            SUBJECT_ID,
            MARKS
        FROM
            MARKS
        WHERE
            ( SUBJECT_ID,
              MARKS ) IN (
                SELECT
                    M.SUBJECT_ID,
                    MAX(M.MARKS)
                FROM
                    MARKS M
                GROUP BY
                    M.SUBJECT_ID
            )
    ) MM
WHERE
    S.STUDENT_ID = MM.STUDENT_ID
    AND SB.SUBJECT_ID = MM.SUBJECT_ID;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3768b569e3d579391d06525edd10cbea)

Thanks

Comment: Thanks it works.

Answer (score 0):

The clause HAVING must be used to add conditions when you use aggregation functions, because the where clause does not allow it,the sintaxys is:

```
**SELECT columns FROM table_name WHERE condition GROUP BY columns HAVING condition**
```

Where HAVING condition is for example:  **max(value) > 1000**

Your subquery should look like this:

```
SELECT student_id, max(value)
FROM   mark
WHERE  student_id = s.subject_id
GROUP BY student_id
HAVING  MAX(value) > 1000;
```

Regards!

Comment: Thanks for better understanding